# Difference between ISO/IEC 27001 and CISSP CBK

Tags: iso27001, cissp

Sorry to ask this, I am quite new to **Security** area. Recently I am trying to introduce some security standards.

After some searching I found this out in this [doc](https://ito.hkbu.edu.hk/pub/is_newsletter/general/Issue_05_ISM/JUCC%20Newsletter-General-5%20ISM.pdf)

> Among them, ISO is the best-known standard for ISMS, which helps to establish and maintain an effective information management system via a continuous improvement approach.

And this statement in this [site](http://resources.infosecinstitute.com/category/certifications-training/cissp/domains/)

> One of the most in-demand IT certification is CISSP®, for Certified Information Systems Security Professionals.

I want to check the domains one by one to try my best to ensure the **security** management is well established based on worldwide **sophisticated standards**.

But as you can see, there are different domains in these standards.

Here are the domain comparisons among them I just drafted up based on [ISO/IEC 27002](http://www.iso27001security.com/html/27002.html) and [CBK](http://resources.infosecinstitute.com/category/certifications-training/cissp/domains/).

[image]

Which one should I turn to? To persuade my boss to apply?

By the way, to me the **CBK** is more like a examination stuff and quite unpractical.

Comment: The CISSP is not a standard at all. It's a personal professional certification. If you are looking for *standards*, remove the CISSP from consideration.

Comment: Oh, yeah ~ You should be right. Thank you, @schroeder. I think I get the point: one for company certificate while CISSP for personal resume. Is it correct?

Comment: You are correct

Comment: @schroeder Thank you, indeed. So confused I was, thank you

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I can see your confusion surrounding this topic.

To start off, the reason why you have the dilemma is because ISO 27001, ISO 27002 and CISSP CBK are all different from each other.

ISO 27001 is an organization-focused standard and provides requirements for your company's ISMS that can be audited.

ISO 27002 focuses on best practices on an individual level (code of practice for use by individuals within a company).

CISSP CBK is a comprehensive framework of all the relevant subjects a security professional should be familiar with (it's not a company standard you can certify your ISMS with).

That being said, if you want official recognition (certification) for your company's ISMS, then choose  ISO 27001. ISO 27002 and CISSP CBK relate to security best practices for INDIVIDUALS within the company.

Comment: While this answer is mostly correct, there is a major mistake here. ISO/IEC 27002 is not focused on individuals like CISSP CBK. While CISSP CBK is a personnel certification for individuals, ISO/IEC 27002 is an international standard for security controls within an organization. These security controls include for instance *Human Resource Security* but also a wide range of other [topics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_27002). Also note, that an organization or an individual cannot be certified with ISO/IEC 27002.

Comment: @stahinja Please review that ISO 27002 is: https://www.iso.org/standard/54533.html

Comment: ISO 27001, ISO 27002 are not different from each other (one guides the other). CISSP is not even comparable to the others. Your ISO 27002 statement is factually incorrect.